# Is this a safe way to execute threads alternatively?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I would like to run code alternatively, so I could stop execution at any moment. Is this code safe?

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var foo = new Foo();
        //wait for interaction (this will be GUI app, so eg. btnNext_click)
        foo.Continue();
        //wait again etc.
        foo.Continue();
        foo.Continue();
        foo.Continue();
        foo.Continue();
        foo.Continue();
    }
}

class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        new Thread(Run).Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Break();
        OnRun();
    }

    protected virtual void OnRun()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
            Break();
        }
        //do something else and break;
    }

    private void Break()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(this);
            Monitor.Wait(this);
        }
    }

    public void Continue()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            Monitor.Pulse(this);
            Monitor.Wait(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Of course I know, that now the application will never ends, but that's not the point.

I need this, because I would like to present steps in some kind of an algorithm and describe what is going on in particular moment, and making everything in one thread would lead to many complications even when using small amount of loops in the code. For example those lines:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    Break();
}
```

should be then replaced with:

```
if (this.i < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i++);
}
```

And that is just a small example of what I want to present. The code will be more complicated than a dummy `for` loop.

Comment: This is weird.  Just don't use a thread.

Comment: @Hans Passant: How would you do this kind of... self explaining (?) code? Inside of `OnRun` I would like to run graph related algorithms and show user explanation of what is going on in this moment eg. with messages and vertices/edges colouring. Splitting such a thing to small pieces would be painful to code.

Comment: The way you have worded the question makes it seem like you are not familiar with the UI threading model for Windows Forms. You should explain what cannot be done with eventing that needs to "alternate" with some separate background thread.

Comment: @David, you cannot pause code execution and wait for user to press the button, and after that resume code execution in the middle of some method.

Comment: How you store the data, and how you present the data should be two different concepts. Can you give a more practical example of what it is you are trying to do? Are you just populating a data structure, one step at a time? If you are actually processing a workflow, you should strongly consider using Workflow Foundation (for many reasons). This will let you "pick up where you left off", you shouldn't write that kind of functionality yourself, imho.

Comment: I really fail to see why people are making a big deal out of this. Is it not reasonable to process work in steps and request user input or show the current state along the way?

Comment: Also I don't think another bloated framework is in order here as setting this type of code up is relatively simple. *See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136039/is-this-a-safe-way-to-execute-threads-alternatively/3136487#3136487*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you check out this [blog post](http://fxcritic.blogspot.com/2008/05/lightweight-fibercoroutines.html) about implementing fibers.

**Code** *(In case the site goes down.)*

```
public class Fiber
{
    private readonly Stack<IEnumerator> stackFrame = new Stack<IEnumerator>();
    private IEnumerator currentRoutine;

    public Fiber(IEnumerator entryPoint)
    {
        this.currentRoutine = entryPoint;
    }

    public bool Step()
    {
        if (currentRoutine.MoveNext())
        {
            var subRoutine = currentRoutine.Current
                           as IEnumerator;
            if (subRoutine != null)
            {
                stackFrame.Push(currentRoutine);
                currentRoutine = subRoutine;
            }
        }
        else if (stackFrame.Count > 0)
        {
            currentRoutine = stackFrame.Pop();
        }
        else
        {
          OnFiberTerminated(
              new FiberTerminatedEventArgs(
                  currentRoutine.Current
              )
          );
          return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler<FiberTerminatedEventArgs> FiberTerminated;

    private void OnFiberTerminated(FiberTerminatedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = FiberTerminated;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}

public class FiberTerminatedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
  private readonly object result;

  public FiberTerminatedEventArgs(object result)
  {
      this.result = result;
  }

  public object Result
  {
      get { return this.result; }
  }
}   

class FiberTest
{
  private static IEnumerator Recurse(int n)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(n);
      yield return n;
      if (n > 0)
      {
          yield return Recurse(n - 1);
      }
  }

  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      var fiber = new Fiber(Recurse(5));
      while (fiber.Step()) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your link. This helps me a lot. I don't really need whole class, at least now. However, the idea of using `Iterator` and `yield` keyword to break (pause) execution is wonderful. Regards

Answer (score 1):

> "...this will be GUI app..."

Then you probably do not want and will not have sequential code like above in `Main()`.

I.e. the main GUI thread will not execute a serial code like above, but generally be idle, repainting, etc. or handling the `Continue` button click.
In that event handler you may better use an [`Auto|ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) to signal the worker to proceed.
In the worker, just wait for the event.

Comment: Thank you. This is so obvious, but like @Hans Passant pointed out, this is a little bit weird, and somehow I haven't thought to use just `AutoResetEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that any time one considers using `Monitor.Wait()`, one should write code so that it would work correctly if the `Wait` sometimes spontaneously acted as though it received a pulse.  Typically, this means one should use the pattern:

```
lock(monitorObj)
{
  while(notYetReady)
    Monitor.Wait(monitorObj);
}
```

For your scenario, I'd suggest doing something like:

```
lock(monitorObj)
{
  turn = [[identifier for this "thread"]];
  Monitor.PulseAll(monitorObj);
  while(turn != [[identifier for this "thread"]])
    Monitor.Wait(monitorObj);
}
```

It is not possible for `turn` to change between its being checked whether it's the current thread's turn to proceed and the `Monitor.Wait`.  Thus, if the `Wait` isn't skipped, the `PulseAll` is guaranteed to awaken it.  Note that the code would work just fine if `Wait` spontaneously acted as though it received a pulse--it would simply spin around, observe `turn` wasn't set for the current thread, and go back to waiting.